# how to remove border from textbox in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, textbox

I want to remove the border which chrome adds for any text box. Here's my html and css which I have already tried.

HTML:

```
<input id="searchbar" type="search" placeholder="Search" />
```

CSS:

```
input[type=search],
input[type=search]:hover,
input[type=search]:focus,
input[type=search]:active
{
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    outline-offset: 0;
    background-color:transparent
}
```

Please advice. There is no border added in IE and the textbox looks perfectly fine.

Update: Attaching the image( I want to achieve what I see on IE10 in Chrome as well)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `-webkit-appearance:none;` will resolve it.  This is a useful hack for form controls in WebKit.

Answer (score 3):

add `outline:none` must solve your problem . please provide url of your site

Answer (score 0):

I have tried both @int32_t 's and @soheil's solution. Even though Chrome and Safari use the same webkit engine. Safari and its other variants IOS, ipad & iphone behave a little differently.

Hence

```
-webkit-appearance:none;
```

worked on Chrome but not on Safari

```
outline:none
```

worked on Safari and not on Chrome

To be on the safer side you can use this

```
.noBorderNoHeighlight{
    border: none;      /* Good browsers universal rule */
    outline: none;     /* safari and its variants  */
    outline-offset: 0; /* IE and its variants  */
    -webkit-appearance:none; /* Chrome and its variants  */
}
```